# Remove class names only within a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I want to remove the class name of several elements, but only within a specified `ID` of an element.

I have tried this but it doesn't work..

```
// Remove classes from hidden elements
$('#sports').('.nd').removeClass();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your browser's console will tell you that you're doing a *TypeError*. That's the first place to look.

Comment: @user1689607 But it won't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar: Right, but basic knowledge of JavaScript syntax and a read through a beginners jQuery tutorial will. *(Actually it's a SyntaxError, which is what my comment originally stated, but in Firefox's JS, it's a TypeError.)*

Comment: I wonder where you got that syntax from `$('#sports').('.nd')`?

Comment: @FelixKling Just a guess haha.... I'm not a big JS person, so thought I'd try that out first before I asked here. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
$('#sports .nd').removeClass('nd');
```

...assuming "nd" is the class you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#sports > .nd').removeClass("nd");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#sports').find('.nd').removeClass('nd');
```

Use the find function.

Or alternatively, follow the other answers and add it to your selector

```
$('#sports > .nd').removeClass('nd');
```

The "less than" operator only goes down one level.

Comment: removeClass() requires a class name

Comment: @Diodeus ["If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed."](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)